# How do I display a java ResultSet visually?

Tags: java, sql, user-interface

I'm looking for a way to display a java.sql.ResultSet on the screen. preferably built-into java or swing. If neither of those have a decent method that's simple, I'd consider spring.

How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop over the results of you ResultSet and put in into a TableModel.

```
DefaultTableModel resultSetToTableModel(
     DefaultTableModel model,
     ResultSet row) throws SQLException
    {
    ResultSetMetaData meta= row.getMetaData();
    if(model==null) model= new DefaultTableModel();
    String cols[]=new String[meta.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i=0;i< cols.length;++i)
        {
        cols[i]= meta.getColumnLabel(i+1);
        }

    model.setColumnIdentifiers(cols);

    while(row.next())
        {
        Object data[]= new Object[cols.length];
        for(int i=0;i< data.length;++i)
             {
             data[i]=row.getObject(i+1);
             }
        model.addRow(data);
        }
    return model;
    }
```

Then you can do something like

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
```

Hopt it helps

Comment: this works decently, but it doesn't appear to have any scroll bars or ability to resize columns if there are many.

Comment: well apparently on a smaller data set, scroll bars and resizing columns works. guess the first table I fed it was excessively wide, possibly long too.

Comment: The indent style you're using makes me want to hurt you!