# SQL data and JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing

I'm trying one sample program for practice and i want to display results of database in JTable. The problem is i have no idea how to do that. I know how to get data from database and display it on text field or console but never tried with JTable. How to do that ?

Consider that i've table which is holding information like person name, age, city and date. i want it to be displayed via JTable. Also is it possible to update the JTable display if i add the option of adding more details in program(i mean adding entries to db then that will show immediately in JTable )?

Any suggestions, pointers on how to proceed is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930745/how-do-i-display-a-java-resultset-visually

Comment: Ok, i can understand it could be duplicate. but i'm asking how to display results from SQL table to JTable,still it is duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC + JTable @ google:

- [Hacking Swing: A JDBC Table Model](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack24/index.html)
- [Mastering the JTable](http://java.sys-con.com/node/36190)
- [Making SQL Queries with JDBC and Displaying Results with Swing](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/java/news/javaex_1000.html)

Comment: Ok. this is helpful but not answering my query completely. anyway, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
try {
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

    // Get the column names
    for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {


    columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1).toUpperCase());
    }

    // Get all rows.
    Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

    while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
    }

    rows.addElement(newRow);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();

    return null;
}
```

}

you can call this method such that way

```
void update_Table() throws ParseException 
    {
        // we used this try catch so that values in table  automatically show(without clicking on any button) when the dialog box open          
                    try
                    {
                   Connection con=MSUTIL.getMSConnection();
                    PreparedStatement  pst=con.prepareStatement("select  payment_mode from PaymentMode");   
                 ResultSet  rs=pst.executeQuery();
                   //here i call that method
                    table.setModel(resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                            mp.paymentmode_ComboBox.addItem(rs.getString("payment_mode"));
                    }

                   }
                    catch(SQLException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                       //this method is for closing the connection
                        MSUTIL.cleanUp(con, pst, rs);
                    }
```

}